# Font and internal line for chemistry package

Tags: fonts, fontspec, chemfig, chemistry

Using `chemfig` package, for drawing the *salicylic acid* I obtain this crop image:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\chemfig{
            % 1
     -[:300]% 2
          =_% 3
               (
          -[:60]% 13
                   (
         -[:120,,,2]HO% 15
                   )
               =O% 14
               )
     -[:300]% 4
               (
         -[,,,1]OH% 12
               )
    =_[:240]% 5
               (
         -[:300]% 8
                   (
             -[:240]% 10
                   )
                   (
             -[:300]% 11
                   )
               -% 9
               )
     -[:180]% 6
    =_[:120]% 7
               (
          -[:60]% -> 2
               )
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Why the line are more closer with the edges of the hexagon? To switch to have more distance and the font (peraphs is Arial), little segments (see the picture - for example below -) do I must use another package for chemistry and to use `fontspec`, `unicode`... `Arial`?

[image]

### EDIT:

In this web site https://www.texdev.net/2012/08/25/exploring-chemfig-customising-appearance/ there is a macro to get a little internal segment with a more distance:

[image]

### How is it must be used?

```
\setdoublesep{0.35700 em}  % 'Bond Spacing'
\setatomsep{1.78500 em}    % 'Fixed Length'
\setbondoffset{0.18265 em} % 'Margin Width'
\newcommand{\bondwidth}{0.06642 em} % 'Line Width'
\setbondstyle{line width = \bondwidth}
```

---

I have improved a bit the code, for the font `helvet`, of the user *@muzimuzhi Z* that I give to him my thank you very much for the work. But I have the internal segment more long.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[scaled=1]{helvet}
\usepackage{chemfig}
%\renewcommand*\printatom[1]{\ensuremath{\mathsf{#1}}}
\renewcommand*\printatom[1]{\sffamily{#1}}%%% only text in helvet clone of Arial
\setchemfig{
  atom sep=1.5em,
  bond style={
    line width=.8pt, line cap=round, line join=round
  }
}



\begin{document}


\chemfig{
            % 1
     -[:300]% 2
          =_% 3
               (
          -[:60]% 13
                   (
         -[:120,,,2]HO% 15
                   )
               =O% 14
               )
     -[:300]% 4
               (
         -[,,,1]OH% 12
               )
    =_[:240]% 5
               (
         -[:300]% 8
                   (
             -[:240]% 10
                   )
                   (
             -[:300]% 11
                   )
               -% 9
               )
     -[:180]% 6
    =_[:120]% 7
               (
          -[:60]% -> 2
               )
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

`chemfig` is configurable. In the following example,

- `\printatom` is redefined to use sans serif font,
- length of bond is shorten by option `atom sep`, and
- line width of bond is made thicker with option `line width`.

Chemfig will auto shorten the inner bond line of a double bond in cycle, but in your example the bonds are drawn without using the cycle syntax. Question [How to alter the bond length of a double bond in chemfig?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/148310/) contains some workarounds, but neither of them is automatic.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\renewcommand*\printatom[1]{\ensuremath{\mathsf{#1}}}
\setchemfig{
  atom sep=1.5em,
  bond style={
    line width=.8pt, line cap=round, line join=round
  }
}

\begin{document}
\chemfig{
            % 1
     -[:300]% 2
          =_% 3
               (
          -[:60]% 13
                   (
         -[:120,,,2]HO% 15
                   )
               =O% 14
               )
     -[:300]% 4
               (
         -[,,,1]OH% 12
               )
    =_[:240]% 5
               (
         -[:300]% 8
                   (
             -[:240]% 10
                   )
                   (
             -[:300]% 11
                   )
               -% 9
               )
     -[:180]% 6
    =_[:120]% 7
               (
          -[:60]% -> 2
               )
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: But the segment into the hexagon seem more closer to the lateral edges. There is few distance. But have you tried using Arial font?

Comment: @Sebastiano I edited the answer to use a longer `atom sep`. Does this look better?

Comment: Surely better :-)...I have upvoted before, I'm sorry. The font it is helvet.